# How to fix: Error (use-package): org-projectile :config: Symbol’s function definition is void: org-projectile:per-repo

Tags: spacemacs

Running spacemacs  0.200.9@25.1.1
Everytime I start spacemacs I get the following error and not sure how to resolve it.

```
Error (use-package): org-projectile :config: Symbol’s function definition is void: org-projectile:per-repo
```

Tried googling the issue and some suggest to switch to the dev branch which I don't know how to do.

Thanks

Comment: I get the same whenever I capture new org-mode task.

Comment: The issue is due to some big refactoring in org-projectile. The issue seems to be known https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/9374 so I hope it will be fixed soon. For me it's more of an inconvenience than a real issue, as the capture still works, but shows an error on the way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears to be a [known issue](http://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/9374) according to the @pmilosev
Thanks for pointing it out.